# Python Chatbot - User Uploads Image

Tags: python, chatbot

I've been trying to figure out a way to get a user to choose an image from their computer that can be essentially uploaded into the program.

The code I have is:

```
elif cmd == 4: #image classification section
    try:
        image_list = []
        for filename in glob.glob('Project/marvel/valid.jpg'):  # assuming gif
            im = Image.open(filename)
            image_list.append(im)
    except:
        print("I'm sorry I can't guess who this person is")
```

But this doesn't do anything really so I think I've misunderstood what it does. Any advice/code/explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you don't actually call your model, so you could maybe start by calling it, for instance by unisng the [`predict` method](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?hl=en#predict)

Comment: @Lescurel I'll work on adding that now thank you but my question at the moment is mainly how to get it so that the program will give the user the option to choose an image. Unless it's all linked?

Comment: Then, I suggest you remove mentions from chatbot, tensorflow, etc, as they are irrelevant to the question. You just want the program to let the user choose an image. The rest is just noise that will prevent people to help you in the most efficient way.

Comment: @Lescurel that is true my apologies I'll do that now. I only added it in in case it affected something but clearly I was wrong. Thanks for your help